# How to create second legend for plot for different sized points

Tags: r

The first legend works fine, as below;

```
legend(-0.108,51.712,
       legend = c("Bakerloo","Central", "Circle", "Distric",
                  "H'smith & City", "Jubilee", "Metropolitan", 
                  "Northern", "Piccadilly", "Victoria",
                  "W'loo & City"), 
       col = c(bakerloocol, centralcol, circlecol, districtcol, 
               hsmithcitycol, jubileecol, metropolitancol, 
               northerncol, piccadillycol, victoriacol, 
               waterloocitycol),
       pch = 16)
```

Then I tried to create a second legend to display relative sizes, elsewhere on the plot so as not to obscure any of the points

```
legend(-0.135,51,46,
       legend = c("100,000", "50,000", "10,000"),
       pch = 16,
       cex = c(10*(100000)/130627, 10*(50000)/130627, 10*(10000)/130627))
```

This one gave an error,

```
Warning message:
In if (xc < 0) text.width <- -text.width :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Which I am not sure how to interpret as it doesn't seem to repeat any of the symbols I used in that line of code.

Any way to show the size of point in the legend appreciated!

Comment: Use code blocks and indent for clarity.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a sidenote: In future questions, people might ask you to produce a [mcve]. In this case it was easy enough to make your code executable by removing the undefined variables `bakerloocol`... etc. but for other examples it might not. Also, I would be as bold to say that if you'd have provided reproducable code in the first place, you'd have gotten an answer more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The warning

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

indicates that an `if` statement has got multiple values despite only (`TRUE` or `FALSE` is allowed inside an `if` statement.

For example,

```
if(c(TRUE, FALSE)){ 
    print('Yes, I'm called!')
}
```

gives this warning. You can see that this makes no sense -- the block after an `if(TRUE)` should be executed and the block after `if(FALSE)` shouldn't. But what about `if(c(TRUE, FALSE))`? It makes no sense and gives this warning.

By searching the line which is mentioned in the warning

> if (xc < 0)

in the source code of `legend` (just type `legend` without `()` in R), you find that `xc` is generated from a variable `Cex` which is `par('cex')` multiplied by the `legend(cex = ...)` argument. If you supply multiple values there, eventually `xc` gets to be multiple values and `[multiple values] < 0` of course give muliple `TRUE`/`FALSE`s -- depending on whether each of the multiple values is < 0. Therefore we have exactly this `if([multiple values])` situation here.

**Conclusion**: Do not supply multiple values to `legend(cex = ...)`. Use `legend(pt.cex = ...)` instead. `legend(cex = ...`) is meant to scale the *whole* legend by some factor.